# How to set up X-Auth-Token in Postman?

Tags: authentication, postman

I have X-Auth-Token for permission to web-site[image]

This key i use in swagger, but how to set up it in Postman for API?

Comment: Hope this link will help you. https://documenter.getpostman.com/view/4315841/RWEnkv4j?version=latest   I think, we have to pass this token as a header as mentioned in the above postman documenter.

Answer (score 12):

In the `Headers` section of the request builder - Just manually add `X-Auth-Token` as the key and then the value of the token.

Comment: It did not work with me and give me this error  "message": "The resource you are looking for is restricted and apparently not within your permissions. Please check your subscription.",

Comment: That's not anything to do with the answer I provided. I was just sharing that you can input that token manually.

Comment: Thank you Danny I do it indeed as you said, i put it manually